# Golden ratio of a circle and square

Tags: geometry, golden-ratio

φ is the golden ratio. In the given figure how can we prove that perimeter of circle is not equal to perimeter of square.

[image]

I am confused as it is not clearly described the figure. Then also how can we prove it.

Comment: Do you know a relation between circle circumference and diameter?  square perimeter and side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The side of the square is
$\sqrt{\phi}
\approx 1.272019649
$
and the diameter of the circle is
$\phi
\approx 1.6180
$
so the perimeter of the square is
$4\sqrt{\phi}
\approx 5.0880
$
and the circumference of the circle is
$\pi\phi
\approx 5.0832
$
so close but not equal.